# Filtering Map<String,List<Object>> to Map<String,Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a Class `EmpObj` which has two parameters `Integer Empid` and `BigDecimal Salary`.
I have a Map which has structure of `Map<String, List<EmpObj>> map`
I want My result to be in format `Map<String, List<Integer>>` map  after filtering All Employees with Salary > 25000. The final List will contain `Name(String)` and `Integer(EmpID)`.

So far My approach:

```
public  class EmpObj {
    Integer empid;
    BigDecimal salary;`


    public EmpObj(Integer empid, BigDecimal salary) {
        this.empid = empid;
        this.salary = salary;
    }}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<EmpObj>> map = new HashMap<>();
        EmpObj e1= new EmpObj(12,new BigDecimal(23000));
        EmpObj e2= new EmpObj(13,new BigDecimal(45000));
        EmpObj e3= new EmpObj(14,new BigDecimal(65000));
        List<EmpObj> o1 = new ArrayList<>();
        o1.add(e1);
        map.put("Vinny",o1);
        List<EmpObj> o2 = new ArrayList<>();
        o2.add(e2);
        map.put("David",o2);
        List<EmpObj> o3 = new ArrayList<>();
        o3.add(e3);
        map.put("Mike",o3);
```

My Java-8 Expression:

```
Map<String,List<EmpObj>> Mp1 =
            map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(s->//Something Here)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue));
         Mp1.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am not getting Result, any suggestion???

My output Need to be **David=[14], Mike=[13]**
My problem is solved.

Comment: @CommonMan I'd use at least `compareTo`, it might not fit into an `int`

Comment: may I ask why do you use such a complicated structure? Why would you like to keep the salary of someone with their id, but their name separate? Why not just make a Employee object that contains the id, name and salary. What I want to know is when you would have the key David, but multiple EmpObj associated with it

Comment: `map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().noneMatch(empObj -> empObj.salary.intValue() < 25000))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> entry.getValue()
            .stream()
            .map(EmpObj::getEmpid)
            .collect(Collectors.toList())));`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalise your post. This may result in a [question ban](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can't compare `BigDecimal` with the usual `>` and `<`, what you could do is create a variable `BigDecimal compareAgainst = BigDecimal.valueOf(25000L)` and use that with your filter statement:

```
...filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getSalary().compareTo(compareAgainst) > 0)
```

I'll let you figure out how `compareTo` works in this case; once filtered you don't need to collect them back to a `Map` simply to print, for example:

```
.forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "  " +  entry.getValue().getEmpid()))
```

Building this solution is up to you, since you said you are a begginer; it's not that complicated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `List<EmpObj>` as a map value you need to *go 1 level down* to `EmpObj` to filter all salaries. At the same time you still need to keep map's key because you want to print it at the end.

You could use `flatMap` and save key and value in `SimpleEntry` like:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> collect = map.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                .filter(empObj -> empObj.getSalary().compareTo(new BigDecimal(25000)) > 0)
                .map(empObj -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), empObj)))
        .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey, 
                 mapping(entry -> entry.getValue().getEmpid(), toList())));

System.out.println(collect);
```